# Assigning names to Tkinter 'entry'

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a 11x11 grid of entries width the following code:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    for j in range(1,11):
        w = Entry(root, width=6, justify=CENTER, relief=RIDGE)
        w.grid(row=i, column=j, ipady=15)
```

Now I wanna be able to set the focus to any of these textboxes, by using some sort of coordinates (ex. setGridFocus(3,4) or something like that). Does anyone one know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
widget = {}
for i in range(1,11):
    for j in range(1,11):
        widget[i,j] = Entry(...)
```